# Updating branch with master but hiding JIRA tags

Tags: git, jira

I've just started as a programmer and getting a bit confused with git.

My team has a remote master branch and I'm working off a separate branch("branchA")

I need to update my branchA with master changes.
Currently I do:

```
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout branchA
git merge
git push
```

The problem I'm having is that when I create a Pull Request to remote branchA, the commits from the master merge are shown. These commits have JIRA tags connected to them but I don't want my Pull Request to be associated with these JIRAs. (We want these JIRAs only associated with PRs to master, not PRs to branchA)

I've been trying with `git reset --soft` then doing a `git commit` and `git push -f`.
This is not working very well because if my previous PR has just been merged into branchA and there are commits that have been committed to master before the branchA merge, then when I do a `git reset`, I lose this branchA commit and it gets lost with the force push.

btw, I'm the only one working on this branch.

I'm probably making it a lot more complicated then it has to be. Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Is the 4th command, `git merge` correct? Are you intending to merge `master` into `branchA` there instead?

Comment: It sounds like you want to use a rebase-oriented work flow. Note that "I'm the only one working on this branch" helps this out immensely since rebase means that everyone else working on the branch must adjust. Here, the list of the other people who must compensate for your rebase is: `[]`. All zero names in this list are the names of the other people who must do extra work after your rebase. :-)

Comment: Yes I'm intending to `git merge master` so I update branchA with the master version.

Comment: Ok thanks Torek. Looking into rebase,  I understand that it copies the commits over to my branch? So when I'm in branchA and I do `rebase master` , doesn't that mean that I still have the master commits with their commit messages (that I don't want shown cause of old JIRA tags)?.  Or do I do a rebase in interactive mode?